# onClick React other classes deactivation once clicked on a link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have created a Sidebar in React, and I designed it so that when I click on a link, it turns activated. However, I want them to be deactivated once clicked on another link, how to achieve that?

```
class Sidebar extends Component {
    state = {
      NavOneActive: false,
      NavTwoActive: false,
      NavThreeActive:false,
      NavFourActive:false,
      NavFiveActive:false,
      NavSixActive:false,
      NavSevenActive:false,
      NavEightActive:false
    }

  render () {
    return (
      <NavPanel dark style={{ backgroundColor: '#2d2e2e', height: '100vh', float:'right'}}>
        <NavTitle style={{ fontFamily: 'IranSans', textAlign: 'Center' }}>
       لوگو اینجا قرار بگیرد
        </NavTitle>
        <NavSection>
          <NavSectionTitle />
          <NavSectionTitle />
          <NavLink key='1' style={linkStyles.base} rightEl={<IoIosAdd style={linkStyles.AddIcon} />} className={this.state.NavOneActive ? 'active' :' ' }
          onClick={() => this.setState({ NavOneActive : !this.state.active })}>
             اضافه کردن فرصت شغلی جدید
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink key='2' style={linkStyles.base} rightEl={<GiIceCube style={linkStyles.Icon} />} className={this.state.NavTwoActive? 'active' :' ' }
          onClick={() => this.setState({ NavTwoActive: !this.state.active })}>
           داشبورد
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink key='3' style={linkStyles.base} rightEl={<FaNetworkWired style={linkStyles.Icon} />} className={this.state.NavThreeActive ? 'active' :' ' }
          onClick={() => this.setState({ NavThreeActive : !this.state.active })}>
           اطلاعات پایه
          </NavLink>
          ...
        </NavSection>
      </NavPanel>

    )
  }
}

export default Radium(Sidebar)
```

Comment: use a single state variable that holds the index / key of the currently active tab, and generate the new nav links by looping through an array containing the link values, and during that process, if the current active tab state and the key of the current link in the array is matched, activate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of making 8 navActives make one navActive which has key

inside State:

```
state={
navActive: '0'
}
```

Inside render for

```
<NavLink key='1' style={linkStyles.base} rightEl={<IoIosAdd style={linkStyles.AddIcon} />} className={this.state.navActive == '1' ? 'active' :' ' }
          onClick={() => this.setState({ navActive:'1' })}>
   اضافه کردن فرصت شغلی جدید
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink key='2' style={linkStyles.base} rightEl={<GiIceCube style={linkStyles.Icon} />} className={this.state.navActive == '2' ? 'active' :' ' }
          onClick={() => this.setState({ navActive:'2' })}>
           داشبورد
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink key='3' style={linkStyles.base} rightEl={<FaNetworkWired style={linkStyles.Icon} />} className={this.state.navActive == '3' ? 'active' :' ' }
          onClick={() => this.setState({ navActive:'3' })}>
           اطلاعات پایه
          </NavLink>
```

Comment: Sorry wrote "=" instead of  ":"

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```js
<NavLink
  to="/hello"
  activeClassName="active"
>Hello</NavLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have moved the text and the icon of the links into a seperate array, 
and when looping through them and displaying it, i am adding the active class if the NavActive matches the index of the current nav being displayed, if so active class is added,

I have not tested the code since I don't have the components required, but you should get a rough idea of how to get it to work.

```
class Sidebar extends Component {
    state = {
        NavActive: null
    }

    links = [
        ['اضافه کردن فرصت شغلی جدید', <IoIosAdd style={linkStyles.AddIcon} />],
        ['داشبورد', <GiIceCube style={linkStyles.Icon} />],
        [' اطلاعات پایه', <FaNetworkWired style={linkStyles.Icon} />]
    ]

    render() {
        return (
            <NavPanel dark style={{ backgroundColor: '#2d2e2e', height: '100vh', float: 'right' }}>
                <NavTitle style={{ fontFamily: 'IranSans', textAlign: 'Center' }}>
                    لوگو اینجا قرار بگیرد
        </NavTitle>
                <NavSection>
                    <NavSectionTitle />
                    <NavSectionTitle />
                    {
                        this.links.map((l, idx) => {
                            let link = links[l];
                            return <NavLink key={idx} style={linkStyles.base} rightEl={link[1]} className={this.state.NavActive === l && 'active'}
                                onClick={() => this.setState({ NavActive: l })}>
                                {link[0]}
                            </NavLink>

                        })
                    }
                </NavSection>
            </NavPanel>
        )
    }
}
```